# How should I save the Jenkins pipeline result?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm learning Jenkins,
I want to save Jenkins pipeline result, and then visit the result by Jenkins REST API.

Can this be achieved?

For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent  any
    stages {
        stage("calculate 1+1") {
               script{
                  def result = 0
                  result = 1+1
               }
         }
}
```

How should I save `result` and then visit it? (I can use `Jenkins` python package: `Jenkins.get_build_info`)

Comment: According Document in Jenkins, Can I custormize `currentBuild.result`? Is `currentBuild.result` is only a enum of  `SUCCESS` `UNSTABLE` `FAILURE`?

Comment: Seems I can not save the result in `currentBuild.result`

Comment: `currentBuild.result` is enum. I suggest to use `writeFile` to write result to workspace, then use `archiveArtifacts` to store it as artifact. You can use REST API to get artifacts.

Comment: Thank you @zett42 
Here is a similar question: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551174/jenkins-pipeline-to-return-results-file-after-build

Answer (score 0):

The result of a pipeline usually is a build somewhere in $WORKSPACE.
You can make Jenkins archive such file(s) using [archiveArtifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) and later retrieve them like [Downloading artifacts from Jenkins using wget or curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432189/downloading-artifacts-from-jenkins-using-wget-or-curl)

If instead you intend to store more metadata about the build (which would reside in build.xml) this is another story. Usually you need plugins that perform such work for you - I am not aware of generic pipeline steps that would do that.